# iOS Swift: TableView numberOfRowsInSection returning wrong count

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UICollectionView with a custom cell. Each custom cell contains a UITableView. The problem I'm having is that the table view is returning the wrong number of rows. When I print data.count in `numberOfRowsInSection` from CustomCell.swift the count is incorrect. But when I print data[indexPath.row].count from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in CustomCell.swift or `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in ViewController.swift the count is correct. What am I doing wrong?

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var collectionView:UICollectionView!
    var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let kCustomCellIdentifier = "CustomCell"

    let data = [[5, 4, 3, 2],[0, 1, 2, 3],[9, 8, 7, 6, 5]]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(kCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        //data[indexPath.row].count returns the correct value
        cell.numbers = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

**CustomCell.swift**

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    let kCustomTableCell = "CustomTableCell"
    var numbers:[Int]!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        tableView = UITableView(frame: frame, style: .Plain)
        tableView.registerClass(CustomTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kCustomTableCell)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        contentView.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //numbers.count returns the wrong value
        return numbers.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //numbers.count returns the correct value
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCustomCell) as! CustomTableCell 
        return cell
    }
```

**Data**

```
data = [[5, 4, 3, 2],[0, 1, 2, 3],[9, 8, 7, 6, 5]]
```

First cell I expect to have 4 rows, second cell I expect to have 4 rows, third cell I expect to have 5 rows. Instead the third cell is returning 4 rows and the data from the first cell.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Sorry if it was confusing. I added more context above. When I said that ViewController.swift was printing the correct value I meant the value I was passing into CustomCell was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good solution, but it works.

```
var numbers:[Int]! {
    didSet{
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```